# SSL Issue : Unable to access website on Android Phones

Tags: iis, lets-encrypt, windows-server-2019

Some of the users are unable to access our website on their Smart Phones (specifically Android 4+ and 6+ versions)

They are facing this warning, whenever accessing.

```
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

But ironically all other websites in the world can be accessed, but not ours.

The certificate is from Let's Encrypt. We have a Windows VPS with PLESK Panel. The certificate chain is working fine.

You can see the [SSLLABS Report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ncr%2Dcet.com&latest)

I have tried a number of things and even scored A+ on SSL Labs. But still does not work. So I have compared our SSL report with another website, one thing I found is that they are using Cloudflare as their DNS service and also using their SSL certificates.

So, as a last resort, I have managed to point my own website DNS with Cloudflare and enabled their SSL/TLS settings. It's still not helping, the website can not be reached on any network or any browser.

How can I find the issue, so that it can be solved?

Comment: Android 6 has been end of life since 2015, 4 since 2013. I wouldn't bother about them. They just don't support modern SSL ciphers, and more importantly, they don't recognize modern Let's Encrypt certificates. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: You are right. But how come other websites with almost the same configuration work? But not ours. There is something that i have missed.

Comment: See https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

Comment: Thank you for the link. I do understand the technical stuff, but it's hard to educate the end users. The only feedback I am receiving is that the comparison. Other sites work, but not yours. So it is a genuine issue in my opinion and there must be a way.

Comment: The sites that work most probably don't use Let's Encrypt.